# Boot camp assistant can only change disk1

Tags: bootcamp, windows, high-sierra, startup

I'm trying to setup and iso file on a flash drive from my macbook using the Boot camp assistant.  It recognizes the iso file, but I am only given one option of using it on disk1 of my own computer and cannot change this to my flash drive.  How can I give Boot camp assistant the ability to recognize the external drive?

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.2

For reference, the iso file is for the windows 10 os.

Answer (score 2):

Bootcamp doesn't have the ability to install Windows on external storage. The Windows installer itself can't install Windows to external storage either, so this feature can't be inplemented to Bootcamp.